# What does Tilemill use to make node.js into a native desktop app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, tilemill

https://github.com/mapbox/tilemill

I've been trying to figure out how tilemill packages their node application into a desktop application for mac, linux or windows. I've searched their github project and I do not see anything that gives any specifics about how they did this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are starting a mini-server on ports 20008 & 20009 using an included nodejs & libs, and then opening it in a webview. Each target platform has basic wrapper that controls node process, and opens a webview pointing to localhost:20009

For example, on Mac, everything (nodejs & libraries & assets) is included in TileMill.app/Resources/ then under TileMill.app/MacOS/ is TileMill which just loads node + index.js (in Resources/) and opens webview.

A simpler cross-platform way to accomplish something similar is to use [node-webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit). Not only do you get easy deployment, but you can call nodejs directly inside the web-layer, instead of having a bunch of web callbacks.  This means that you can do things like access files directly, and don't need to keep your client/server separate.

Comment: Basically this, though to be clear the cross-platform UI/browser wrapper is a smaller concern than the requirement to static-compile all binary dependencies of the app.

Comment: Yeh, node-webkit can be used in this way. I use it for my new version of [arduinoscope](https://github.com/konsumer/arduinoscope) to compile it's binary dep of the serial lib. Each target needs you to compile the modules for that platform (npm install, which compiles it's binary deps.)

Answer (score 0):

its just a packaged app, the dependecies can be found in `package.json` as for distribution and installing it uses,
nsis installer to deploy the app, since the `node.exe` doesn't have many dependecies (its one .exe) . So when installing it simply extracts from .exe to local directory, and delivers the application, if you explore the local directory, you will even find `node_modules` folder where every module is pre-installed.

Tilemill won't break on any update of your local node.js , because it uses its fixed version `node.exe`.